# async and defer loading with document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, deferred

I guess I am a little late to the party, but I am really finding it hard to get my head around 'async' and 'defer'.

From reading docs, I understood that the following mixture below would allow for all 'async' to load in any order before the 'defer' (scripts.js) would run. However, in my testing, I am seeing the defered 'scripts.js' running before the async have loaded, which then causes issues where libraries are not ready to be initialised.

```
<script async src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script async src="/-/js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script async src="/-/js/fancybox.js"></script>
<script async src="/-/js/lazysizes.js"></script>
<script async src="/-/js/slideshow.js"></script>
<script async src="/-/js/form.js"></script>
<script async src="/-/js/watch.js"></script>
<script defer src="/-/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

The contents of the 'scripts.js' is wrapped in a document ready function, which I also believed would only run after the 'async' scripts had loaded fully:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

From the docs, I understand that any 'defer' will load in order, so should I instead being applying 'defer' to all, or should a different document function be used?

**EDIT** - I should mention that the 'scripts.js' script relies on the other scripts.

Comment: From MDN: `This is a Boolean attribute indicating that the browser should, if possible, load the script asynchronously.` (async), `This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.` (defer). So, Defer is fired after the document has been parsed, but adding `async` to the other may not guarantee that the script execution will happen after all the aboves have been included. Contrarely, it means the exact opposite. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: Thank you. I had completely misunderstood! In this case, am I correct in understanding that the use of defer on all, along with document ready in the scripts.js would remove the resource blocking, but still initialise correctly?

Comment: Yes, it would. However, I wouldn't even use `defer` in such case, just remove both async and defer and you should be good. Use `defer` if you need to execute some code once the document is parsed, use `async` if you're **sure** that such script specifically is **unneeded** in the init process. Take google maps as an example, where the script tag included have **both** async and defer, it should clarify everything.

Comment: I am looking to speed up the initial load. Do you know of any negative of using the defer in this case?

Comment: No, but since the browser will cache all the scripts (the jquery one may be cached already, since it's on a CDN), only the first load will impact, all the next ones will be blinkingly fast :).

Comment: Thank you. I agree, but Google is throwing a wobbly about it!